# XeLaTeX won't use superscript-table of OTF

Tags: math-mode, xetex, superscripts

The following MWE will show you the problem I encountered today.

As asked, the problem I see, is that in math-mode the numbers aren't displayed as in the first line. David Carlisle stated, that this is caused by the usage of Computer Modern as Math-Font.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}% ,Scale=MatchLowercase} bug in current Biolinum
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine Mono O}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
        {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}1234567890 Libertine}\newline
        $1^{1234567890 Libertine}$\\
        \textsuperscript{1234567890}\\
        \begin{equation}
            1^{1234567890}
        \end{equation}
        Test -- {\bfseries Test}\\
        \textit{Test} -- \textit{\bfseries Test}\\
        \texttt{Test} -- \texttt{\bfseries Test}\\
        \textsc{Test} -- \textsc{\bfseries Test}\\
        \textsf{Test} -- \textsf{\bfseries Test}\\
        0123456789 -- {\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textit{0123456789} -- \textit{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \texttt{0123456789} -- \texttt{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textsc{0123456789} -- \textsc{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textsf{0123456789} -- \textsf{\bfseries 0123456789}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the following picture, the superscript isn't used correctly in math-mode while it is used with `addfontfeature`.

[image: XeLaTeX with Linux Libertine]

Comment: There's a lot of numbers:-), it might help if you said what exactly the problem you see, it if you annotated the image with some red circles or something

Comment: math is still using computer modern, what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `newtxmath` with the `libertine` option:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{Linux Libertine Mono O}


\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
        {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}1234567890 Libertine}\newline
        $1^{1234567890 Libertine}$\\
        \textsuperscript{1234567890}\\
        \begin{equation}
            1^{1234567890}
        \end{equation}
        Test -- {\bfseries Test}\\
        \textit{Test} -- \textit{\bfseries Test}\\
        \texttt{Test} -- \texttt{\bfseries Test}\\
        \textsc{Test} -- \textsc{\bfseries Test}\\
        \textsf{Test} -- \textsf{\bfseries Test}\\
        0123456789 -- {\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textit{0123456789} -- \textit{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \texttt{0123456789} -- \texttt{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textsc{0123456789} -- \textsc{\bfseries 0123456789}\\
        \textsf{0123456789} -- \textsf{\bfseries 0123456789}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I removed the `Numbers=OldStyle` option for better comparison.

The size of superscripts doesn't match, because the superscript glyphs in the OTF font are not meant for math.

[image]